# Process for total derivative of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

In a text I'm reading there is a result given for a certain derivative which I'm trying to derive on my own. I've experienced some difficulty with this, with possible things tripping me up being:

1. The variable the derivative is taken with respect to is a difference of two variables (and the function itself is also a difference of two variables).
2. The input and output variables are related through intermediary variables ($q_1, q_2$) without an analytical inverse.
3. Partial derivatives do not have reciprocity of inverses, in general.

---

To summarize the problem statement:

Find $$\frac{di}{dv}$$ where:

$$i=i_1-i_2$$
$$v=v_1-v_2$$

And for $k=1, 2$:
$$v_k = U_T \left( 2(q_k-1) + \ln (q_k) \right)$$
$$i_k = q_k^2 + q_k$$

There are also two additional constraints, namely that the sum of the $i_k$'s and $v_k$'s are always constant:

$$i_1+i_2=I_0$$
$$v_1+v_2=V_0$$

The given result which I'm trying to derive is:

$$ \frac{di}{dv} = \frac{2}{U_T} \frac{q_1 q_2}{q_1+q_2}$$

---

My attempt to solve this goes as follows:

$$\frac{di}{dv} = \frac{d(i_1-i_2)}{d(v_1-v_2)} = \frac{\partial (i_1-i_2)}{\partial v_1}-\frac{\partial (i_1-i_2)}{\partial v_2} = \left( \frac{\partial i_1}{\partial v_1} - \frac{\partial i_2}{\partial v_1} \right) - \left( \frac{\partial i_1}{\partial v_2} - \frac{\partial i_2}{\partial v_2}\right)$$

From here the first and last terms (the non-"cross terms") on the rightmost side of the equality seem easiest to calculate:

$$\frac{\partial i_k}{\partial v_k} = \frac{\partial i_k}{\partial q_k} \frac{\partial q_k}{\partial v_k} $$

However, it's not possible to analytically isolate and find $q_k$ as a function of $v_k$. I can find $\frac{\partial i_k}{\partial q_k}$as well as $\frac{\partial v_k}{\partial q_k}$, and then the latter in terms of the former:

$$\frac{\partial i_k}{\partial q_k} = 2q_k+1$$
$$\frac{\partial v_k}{\partial q_k} = U_T \left(  \frac{2q_k+1}{q_k} \right) = \frac{U_T}{q_k} \frac{\partial i_k}{\partial q_k}$$

However at this point I feel stuck, since if my understanding is correct, the reciprocal of the partial derivative is not the partial derivative of the inverse function in general:

$$\frac{\partial q_k}{\partial v_k} \neq \frac{1}{\frac{\partial v_k}{\partial q_k}}$$

I have seen other questions on this site about the conditions for reciprocity of these partial derivatives but I'm not sure how to apply them here.

As for the "cross-terms", I am even less certain. I think that this is where I would use the constraint that $i_1+i_2=I_0$, and I might try to say something like:

$$\frac{\partial i_1}{\partial v_k} + \frac{\partial i_2}{\partial v_k} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial i_1}{\partial v_k} = - \frac{\partial i_2}{\partial v_k}$$

However at this point I start to doubt my understanding of the meaning of these partial derivatives entirely. For example, suppose $k=1$ and we're looking at the statement

$$\frac{\partial i_1}{\partial v_1} = - \frac{\partial i_2}{\partial v_1}$$

I interpret the left hand side as meaning "the amount that $i_1$ changes solely due to a change in $v_1$, with all else constant". However, because of the two constraints above taken together, $v_1$ and $v_2$ can't change independently, rather they need to vary differentially around $V_0$, such that if $v_1 = V_0 + \Delta V$ then we must have $v_2 = V_0 - \Delta V$. This issue seems to apply to the previous results as well.

I may be missing some very clear things here, if anyone can provide guidance that would be greatly appreciated.